# Intel Wireless AC 9462 not working w/ 18.04 LTS

Tags: networking, drivers, iwlwifi

So here we go again. Yet another Wi-Fi problem in a clean Ubuntu 18.04 LTS installation.

```
dmesg | grep iwl
```

gives me this:

```
[    1.644366] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    1.674861] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 43.95eb4e97.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    1.694573] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 9462, REV=0x354
[    6.709017] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to load firmware chunk!
[    6.709020] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: iwlwifi transaction failed, dumping registers
[    6.709021] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: iwlwifi device config registers:
[    6.709093] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000000: 02f08086 00100406 02800000 00800000 a1218004 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    6.709094] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000020: 00000000 00000000 00000000 42a48086 00000000 000000c8 00000000 000001ff
[    6.709095] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: iwlwifi device memory mapped registers:
[    6.709123] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000000: 58489004 00000040 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    6.709124] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000020: 00000011 0c040005 00000351 d55555d5 d55555d5 d55555d5 80008040 001f0040
[    6.709141] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Could not load the [0] uCode section
[    6.709161] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start INIT ucode: -110
[    6.709162] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Collecting data: trigger 15 fired.
[    6.916301] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failing on timeout while stopping DMA channel 8 [0x0bad1122]
[    6.928661] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

and the network controller in `lspci` is, for some reason, listed as `02f0` instead of Intel Dual Band Wireless 9462:

```
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 02f0
```

Answer (score 6):

I solved it. Here are the commands to enter in the terminal in order. Make sure you either have Ethernet or some external WiFi adapter to access the Internet. I used a USB WiFi Adapter I use for hacking. -

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git build-essential
git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/backport-iwlwifi.git
cd backport-iwlwifi/
make defconfig-iwlwifi-public
sed -i 's/CPTCFG_IWLMVM_VENDOR_CMDS=y/# CPTCFG_IWLMVM_VENDOR_CMDS is not set/' .config
make -j4
sudo make install
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

Comment: Having wired Ethernet available is always a very good idea for system installations.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me!

Comment: I bought the same model yesterday, and your post saved my day. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There are other options now, `backports-iwlwifi-dkms` is in Ubuntu repos and if that version isn't new enough, there is this: [https://launchpad.net/~canonical-hwe-team/+archive/ubuntu/backport-iwlwifi](https://launchpad.net/%7Ecanonical-hwe-team/+archive/ubuntu/backport-iwlwifi)

The advantage to the dkms package is that you do not have to reinstall the backports after every kernel update.

Comment: works on 20.04.3! thanks

Comment: Works, just make sure you have connection (eg. u can use Wifi hot spot from your mobile device) or connect via cable.