# Ubuntu 18.04 fail to load Intel 9560 wireless firmware

Tags: 18.04, thinkpad, iwlwifi

I have a ***Thinkpad X1 carbon 7th gen*** with an **Intel 9560 wireless** card. When I installed the Ubuntu 18.04 I noticed the wireless does not work.

[image: My Wireless Situatio!]

I've read some of the answers on other similar questions and ran some commands that were mentioned in those questions.

Here is the result of `dmesg | grep iwl`:

```
[3.845229] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[3.879509] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 43.95eb4e97.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[3.926980] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 9560, REV=0x354
[8.969971] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to load firmware chunk!
[8.969975] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: iwlwifi transaction failed, dumping registers
[8.969976] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: iwlwifi device config registers:
[8.970161] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000000: 02f08086 00100406 02800000 00800000 ea238004 00000000 00000000 00000000
[8.970162] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000020: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00308086 00000000 000000c8 00000000 000001ff
[8.970163] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: iwlwifi device memory mapped registers:
[8.970194] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000000: 18489004 00000040 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[8.970196] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000020: 00000011 0c040005 00000351 d55555d5 d55555d5 d55555d5 80008040 001f0040
[8.970215] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Could not load the [0] uCode section
[8.970219] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start INIT ucode: -110
[8.970220] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Collecting data: trigger 15 fired.
[9.193626] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failing on timeout while stopping DMA channel 8 [0x0bad1122]
[9.206151] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

And here are the results of `iwconfig`:

```
enp0s31f6  no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

enxc025e9292f1d  no wireless extensions.
```

I also updated & upgraded all packages of my Linux.

How can I fix this issue? Any Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same situation as yours, down to the `dmesg` log level (iwlwifi INIT ), with my ThinkPad X1 Carbon Gen 7.

I found that the [solution of Hrijul Bhatnagar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182722/intel-wireless-ac-9462-not-working-w-18-04-lts) works for me.

Prerequisite: either tether, or have a wired connection.

Run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git build-essential
git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/backport-iwlwifi.git
cd backport-iwlwifi/
make defconfig-iwlwifi-public
sed -i 's/CPTCFG_IWLMVM_VENDOR_CMDS=y/# CPTCFG_IWLMVM_VENDOR_CMDS is not set/' .config
make -j4
sudo make install
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

Reboot.

Hope it works for you too.

Edit: Hello @Shawn Dooley,

Before I attempted this solution, I have also:

- Turn off Secure Boot ( in The Bios Menu ) ( second attempt )
- `apt-get upgrade` ( after the update ) ( first attempt )
- Downloaded new firmware driver, and put it in /lib/firmware. ( third attempt )

  Link to download: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html

Doing Hrijul Bhatnagar's solution was my fourth attempt.

Comment: I've done your exact prescription and It worked like a charm. :D

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Mate you saved my life here... copy pasting and after reboot.... OMG canot believe I sunk 4 hours into solution when yours was the only working one :O Thank you !

Comment: Hi, I am trying this solutiom to my problem, but when I run

```make defconfig-iwlwifi-public```

I get errors:

```Makefile:40: recipe for target 'defconfig-iwlwifi-public' failed```

Anybody knows what might be happening?