# "No Wi-Fi Adapter found" in Ubuntu 18.04 after update

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, dell, intel

I'm using "Dell Vostro 5490", OS Ubuntu 18.04, Wifi module "Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 9462".

For two months everything worked well. Once after update I reboot Dell and Wi-Fi adapter is not visible anymore. In the "Settings" I see message "No Wi-Fi adapter found".

`sudo rfkill list` shows Bluetooth only

`dmesg` shows **Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 9462, REV=0x354**

I tried to use answer from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1182725/375968) and it works. However, then I had another update of Ubuntu and needed to reboot. After another reboot Wi-Fi didn't work again.

I tried again the same answer. Before `make install` I run `git pull origin master`. After that during reboot Ubuntu just stuck. From the root mode I just run `make uninstall` in backport-iwlwifi. Now Ubuntu works, but without Wi-Fi.

Did anybody encounter this problem? Can you give any solution or advice?