# Intel AC9462 wifi not found in 19.10 (Ubuntu and Kubuntu both)

Tags: wireless, dell, intel

I searched the entire web and tried everything, but the wifi only works on liveusb mode, on the actual installation on the SSD, it does't even show the available networks.

I tried downloading the Intel AC 9462 firmware from Intel's website and copied it to /lib/firmware. Verified that the iwlwifi driver is being used but nothing works.

My notebook is a Dell [Inspiron 14 5490](https://topics-cdn.dell.com/pdf/inspiron-14-5490-laptop_Users-Guide_en-us.pdf), it does't have a ethernet cable connection.

Could someone please help me?

Edit:

```
sudo rfkill list && lspci -knn | grep Net -A3

0: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: yes
        Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02f0]
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:42a4]
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
        Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Kernel: 5.3.0-40-generic

I managed to connect my smartphone using USB Tethering to get internet like @Gryu said, and executed the commands described in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182722/intel-wireless-ac-9462-not-working-w-18-04-lts) post. Now the wifi is working, but sometimes it doesn't find my network, even if the notebook is right beside the router. I don't know if it's related, and I admit that I don't know what these commands actually do.

But either way, it's not ideal to have to have a smartphone everytime I do a fresh install to make the wifi work, any ideas of why this happened?

Comment: Could you share internet with your laptop using your phone's usb tethering?

Comment: Please run _sudo rfkill list && lspci -knn | grep Net -A3_ then copy as text the results. Return here, click [edit], and paste the results as text into your question. Please do not use Add Comments. A USB3-Ethernet adapter could be helpful in getting you connected. FYI, the Intel AC9462 _iwlwifi_ drivers are already in the kernel, _all praise to Linus_.

Comment: Are you running kernel version 5.3.0-40? Verify from the terminal: `uname -r` If so, reboot and at the GRUB menu, select an earlier kernel version than -40. Does your wireless work now? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.