# wireless adapter not found

Tags: networking, dual-boot, drivers, 19.10

I'm currently using Ubuntu 19.10 alongside Windows 10 on my *Lenovo ThinkPad L13 Yoga (Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160 MHz)*.
Until about a week ago, I had no problems connecting to a wifi in Ubuntu, but now it doesn't seem to even find the wireless adapter.
Entering `lspci -nn` in the terminal yields:

```
~$ lspci -nn
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9b61] (rev 0c)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9b41] (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem [8086:1903] (rev 0c)
00:08.0 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model [8086:1911]
00:12.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02f9]
00:13.0 Serial controller [0700]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02fc]
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02ed]
00:14.2 RAM memory [0500]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02ef]
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02f0]
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02e8]
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02e0]
00:1d.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02b0] (rev f0)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02b4] (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0284]
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02c8]
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02a3]
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02a4]
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (10) I219-V [8086:0d4f]
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:011a]
05:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:522a] (rev 01)
```

`lshw -C network` doesn't seem to find any wireless device either:

```
~$ lshw -C network 
 *-network:0
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:71338000-7133bfff
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (10) I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 00
       serial: 48:2a:e3:6a:05:e0
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.5-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:125 memory:71300000-7131ffff
```

I already tried using `sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source`, as it didn't work, I'm not sure about what to do next.

Edit: Output from `dmesg | grep iwl; rfkill list`:

```
[    4.099546] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.119928] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 43.2.23.17
[    4.120153] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 48.4fa0041f.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    4.189238] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz, REV=0x354
[    5.208543] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Collecting data: trigger 15 fired.
[    5.208646] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    5.208649] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000000, count: -504627070
[    5.208650] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 48.4fa0041f.0
[    5.208652] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA0793E82 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
[    5.208653] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x94F2798B | trm_hw_status0
[    5.208655] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA3517CB7 | trm_hw_status1
[    5.208656] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x29F73D28 | branchlink2
[    5.208657] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x73CEE02C | interruptlink1
[    5.208658] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xB77FF422 | interruptlink2
[    5.208660] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0355F295 | data1
[    5.208661] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x742EE3B9 | data2
[    5.208662] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xE983D93C | data3
[    5.208663] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x177D06CF | beacon time
[    5.208665] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC594F2D6 | tsf low
[    5.208666] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xF0BCFFD6 | tsf hi
[    5.208667] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x06CCFC58 | time gp1
[    5.208669] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x2B3550DA | time gp2
[    5.208670] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFA1E57AB | uCode revision type
[    5.208671] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x6D02FBAA | uCode version major
[    5.208672] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7D7FCEE7 | uCode version minor
[    5.208674] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x2A3678BE | hw version
[    5.208675] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xB101DB5D | board version
[    5.208676] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x39CAC9AF | hcmd
[    5.208677] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7AED70E0 | isr0
[    5.208679] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0219DE93 | isr1
[    5.208680] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFFED5D51 | isr2
[    5.208681] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x42A89C4E | isr3
[    5.208682] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x17E8C34F | isr4
[    5.208684] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xF984FDCD | last cmd Id
[    5.208685] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x450BFACB | wait_event
[    5.208686] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xD0E96934 | l2p_control
[    5.208687] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x76E99CFA | l2p_duration
[    5.208689] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7E8E1EF9 | l2p_mhvalid
[    5.208690] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x04719409 | l2p_addr_match
[    5.208691] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA69BA184 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[    5.208693] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x108309B2 | timestamp
[    5.208694] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xE72FDB15 | flow_handler
[    5.208729] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    5.208730] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000000, count: 7
[    5.208732] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x201013F1 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[    5.208733] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[    5.208734] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC008CF5C | umac branchlink2
[    5.208735] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink1
[    5.208737] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
[    5.208738] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | umac data1
[    5.208739] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | umac data2
[    5.208740] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300202 | umac data3
[    5.208742] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000030 | umac major
[    5.208743] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4FA0041F | umac minor
[    5.208744] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00005CA2 | frame pointer
[    5.208746] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0887F58 | stack pointer
[    5.208747] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | last host cmd
[    5.208748] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[    5.208766] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[    5.208769] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[    5.208772] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[    5.208775] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDC5532FB | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[    5.208778] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A384 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[    5.208781] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xD7FE424C | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[    5.208784] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xEA637FA6 | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[    5.208787] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA65FC5CC | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[    5.208790] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x56BE36AC | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[    5.208793] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    5.208798] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300202 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    5.208803] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000485B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[    5.208838] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[    5.208866] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x5c0f, CPU2 Status: 0x3
[    5.208868] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[    5.208871] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Firmware not running - cannot dump error
[    5.220602] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `dmesg | grep iwl; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Please note: "Failed to run INIT ucode: -110" and then check the duplicate. As yours is an Intel wireless device, please remove the Broadcom driver: `sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source`