# AX210 wifi not working on Ubuntu21.04

Tags: networking, iwlwifi

**For new watchers: AX210 works in ubuntu22 with no fix.**

My pc(msi GS66 Stealth 11UH) cannot work AX210 on ubuntu21.04, kernel 5.12.19-051219-generic.

My problem is similar to these thread but I couldn't solve this from these discussion.
https://community.intel.com/t5/Wireless/No-Wi-Fi-Adapter-Found-Intel-AX210-on-Ubuntu-20-04/td-p/1295890

[Ubuntu 20.04 LTS driver Intel Wi-Fi 6E AX210 160MHz](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1326386/ubuntu-20-04-lts-driver-intel-wi-fi-6e-ax210-160mhz)

Does anyone solved this problem on Ubuntu20.04 or 21.04?

my status are below. If need more information, please tell me.

Thank you.

2021/08/29 status(on ubuntu21.10, solved)

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep iwl
[    2.151460] Loading modules backported from iwlwifi
[    2.151461] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:9340:55438a77
[    2.177385] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.189994] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-67.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.192947] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    2.192969] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 0.63.2.1
[    2.193367] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: loaded firmware version 66.55c64978.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-66.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.257479] Modules linked in: iwlmvm(OE+) snd_soc_core snd_compress x86_pkg_temp_thermal mei_hdcp mac80211(OE) intel_rapl_msr intel_powerclamp ac97_bus fjes(-) coretemp snd_pcm_dmaengine libarc4 i915(+) snd_pcm kvm_intel snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi kvm iwlwifi(OE) snd_seq crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel drm_kms_helper cfg80211(OE) crypto_simd snd_seq_device cryptd cec glue_helper snd_timer rc_core i2c_algo_bit processor_thermal_device input_leds processor_thermal_rfim snd fb_sys_fops mei_me syscopyarea processor_thermal_mbox intel_pmt_telemetry processor_thermal_rapl sysfillrect intel_cstate ee1004 wmi_bmof hid_multitouch(+) msi_wmi intel_pmt_class compat(OE) serio_raw sysimgblt efi_pstore intel_rapl_common soundcore mei int340x_thermal_zone intel_soc_dts_iosf gpio_keys mac_hid int3400_thermal intel_hid acpi_thermal_rel soc_button_array sparse_keymap acpi_tad acpi_pad sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc ppdev lp drm parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4
[    2.258069] Modules linked in: iwlmvm(OE+) snd_soc_core snd_compress x86_pkg_temp_thermal mei_hdcp mac80211(OE) intel_rapl_msr intel_powerclamp ac97_bus fjes(-) coretemp snd_pcm_dmaengine libarc4 i915(+) snd_pcm kvm_intel snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi kvm iwlwifi(OE) snd_seq crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel drm_kms_helper cfg80211(OE) crypto_simd snd_seq_device cryptd cec glue_helper snd_timer rc_core i2c_algo_bit processor_thermal_device input_leds processor_thermal_rfim snd fb_sys_fops mei_me syscopyarea processor_thermal_mbox intel_pmt_telemetry processor_thermal_rapl sysfillrect intel_cstate ee1004 wmi_bmof hid_multitouch(+) msi_wmi intel_pmt_class compat(OE) serio_raw sysimgblt efi_pstore intel_rapl_common soundcore mei int340x_thermal_zone intel_soc_dts_iosf gpio_keys mac_hid int3400_thermal intel_hid acpi_thermal_rel soc_button_array sparse_keymap acpi_tad acpi_pad sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc ppdev lp drm parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4
[    2.258636] Modules linked in: soundwire_bus iwlmvm(OE+) snd_soc_core snd_compress x86_pkg_temp_thermal mei_hdcp mac80211(OE) intel_rapl_msr intel_powerclamp ac97_bus fjes(-) coretemp snd_pcm_dmaengine libarc4 i915(+) snd_pcm kvm_intel snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi kvm iwlwifi(OE) snd_seq crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel drm_kms_helper cfg80211(OE) crypto_simd snd_seq_device cryptd cec glue_helper snd_timer rc_core i2c_algo_bit processor_thermal_device input_leds processor_thermal_rfim snd fb_sys_fops mei_me syscopyarea processor_thermal_mbox intel_pmt_telemetry processor_thermal_rapl sysfillrect intel_cstate ee1004 wmi_bmof hid_multitouch(+) msi_wmi intel_pmt_class compat(OE) serio_raw sysimgblt efi_pstore intel_rapl_common soundcore mei int340x_thermal_zone intel_soc_dts_iosf gpio_keys mac_hid int3400_thermal intel_hid acpi_thermal_rel soc_button_array sparse_keymap acpi_tad acpi_pad sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc ppdev lp drm parport ip_tables x_tables
[    2.259131] Modules linked in: soundwire_bus iwlmvm(OE+) snd_soc_core snd_compress x86_pkg_temp_thermal mei_hdcp mac80211(OE) intel_rapl_msr intel_powerclamp ac97_bus fjes(-) coretemp snd_pcm_dmaengine libarc4 i915(+) snd_pcm kvm_intel snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi kvm iwlwifi(OE) snd_seq crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel drm_kms_helper cfg80211(OE) crypto_simd snd_seq_device cryptd cec glue_helper snd_timer rc_core i2c_algo_bit processor_thermal_device input_leds processor_thermal_rfim snd fb_sys_fops mei_me syscopyarea processor_thermal_mbox intel_pmt_telemetry processor_thermal_rapl sysfillrect intel_cstate ee1004 wmi_bmof hid_multitouch(+) msi_wmi intel_pmt_class compat(OE) serio_raw sysimgblt efi_pstore intel_rapl_common soundcore mei int340x_thermal_zone intel_soc_dts_iosf gpio_keys mac_hid int3400_thermal intel_hid acpi_thermal_rel soc_button_array sparse_keymap acpi_tad acpi_pad sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc ppdev lp drm parport ip_tables x_tables
[    2.263007] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: Detected Killer(R) Wi-Fi 6E AX1675x 160MHz Wireless Network Adapter (210NGW), REV=0x420
[    2.269781] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: WRT: Failed to set DRAM buffer for alloc id 1, ret=-1
[    2.269783] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: WRT: Failed to set DRAM buffer for alloc id 2, ret=-1
[    2.269783] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: WRT: Failed to set DRAM buffer for alloc id 3, ret=-1
[    2.415606] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: loaded PNVM version 0xd35929d8
[    2.427570] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: Detected RF GF, rfid=0x10d000
[    2.497019] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: base HW address: 7c:50:79:5a:76:c5
[    2.513928] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0 wlp48s0: renamed from wlan0
[    2.951548] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: WRT: Failed to set DRAM buffer for alloc id 1, ret=-1
```

```
$ lshw -C network
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Killer E3000 2.5GbE Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:2e:00.0
       logical name: enp46s0
       version: 06
       serial: d8:bb:c1:25:32:20
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.11.0-33-generic firmware=rtl8125b-2_0.0.2 07/13/20 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:16 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:84300000-8430ffff memory:84310000-84313fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX210/AX211/AX411 160MHz
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:30:00.0
       logical name: wlp48s0
       version: 1a
       serial: 7c:50:79:5a:76:c5
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.11.0-33-generic firmware=66.55c64978.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-66.uc ip=192.168.10.54 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes
       resources: irq:16 memory:84200000-84203fff
```

2021/08/13's status

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep iwl
[  538.840479] Loading modules backported from iwlwifi
[  538.840480] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:8613:3ae69204
[  538.857251] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[  538.857253] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: WRT: Unsupported TLV 0x1000008 version 2
[  538.857255] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: WRT: Unsupported TLV 0x1000008 version 2
[  538.857261] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: WRT: Unsupported TLV 0x1000008 version 2
[  538.857261] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: WRT: Unsupported TLV 0x1000008 version 2
[  538.857262] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: WRT: Unsupported TLV 0x1000008 version 2
[  538.857263] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: WRT: Unsupported TLV 0x1000008 version 2
[  538.857264] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: WRT: Unsupported TLV 0x1000008 version 2
[  538.857265] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: WRT: Unsupported TLV 0x1000008 version 2
[  538.857265] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: WRT: Unsupported TLV 0x1000008 version 2
[  538.857266] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: WRT: Unsupported TLV 0x1000008 version 2
[  538.857267] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: WRT: Unsupported TLV 0x1000008 version 2
[  538.857267] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: WRT: Unsupported TLV 0x1000008 version 2
[  538.857268] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: WRT: Unsupported TLV 0x1000008 version 2
[  538.857269] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: WRT: Unsupported TLV 0x1000008 version 2
[  538.857270] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: WRT: Unsupported TLV 0x1000008 version 2
[  538.857270] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: WRT: Unsupported TLV 0x1000008 version 2
[  538.857271] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: WRT: Unsupported TLV 0x1000008 version 2
[  538.857272] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: WRT: Unsupported TLV 0x1000008 version 2
[  538.857272] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: WRT: Unsupported TLV 0x1000008 version 2
[  538.857273] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: WRT: Unsupported TLV 0x1000008 version 2
[  538.857274] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: WRT: Unsupported TLV 0x1000008 version 2
[  538.857275] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: WRT: Unsupported TLV 0x1000008 version 2
[  538.857276] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: WRT: Unsupported TLV 0x1000008 version 2
[  538.857276] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: WRT: Unsupported TLV 0x1000008 version 2
[  538.857279] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 0.63.2.1
[  538.857500] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: loaded firmware version 66.55c64978.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-66.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[  538.869075] iwlmvm: Unsupported amsdu_size: 2000
[  538.869081] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz, REV=0x420
[  539.020829] WARNING: CPU: 14 PID: 3287 at /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/8613/build/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/mvm/fw.c:243 iwl_alive_fn+0x237/0x270 [iwlmvm]
[  539.020890] Modules linked in: iwlmvm(OE+) mac80211(OE) libarc4 iwlwifi(OE) cfg80211(OE) compat(OE) rfcomm xt_conntrack nft_chain_nat xt_MASQUERADE nf_nat nf_conntrack_netlink nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 xfrm_user xfrm_algo nft_counter xt_addrtype nft_compat nf_tables libcrc32c nfnetlink br_netfilter bridge stp llc hid_logitech_hidpp cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher overlay af_alg bnep nvidia_uvm(POE) nvidia_drm(POE) nvidia_modeset(POE) joydev hid_logitech_dj snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp snd_soc_hdac_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic snd_soc_dmic snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_soc_hdac_hda soundwire_intel soundwire_generic_allocation soundwire_cadence snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_pci snd_sof snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi soundwire_bus ledtrig_audio snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_soc_core snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine btusb uvcvideo btrtl btbcm videobuf2_vmalloc btintel videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2
[  539.021179] CPU: 14 PID: 3287 Comm: irq/157-iwlwifi Tainted: P        W  OE     5.12.11-051211-generic #202106161201
[  539.021190] RIP: 0010:iwl_alive_fn+0x237/0x270 [iwlmvm]
[  539.021290]  iwl_notification_wait+0xba/0xf0 [iwlwifi]
[  539.021333]  iwl_mvm_rx_common+0x84/0x2a0 [iwlmvm]
[  539.021379]  iwl_mvm_rx_mq+0x9d/0xf0 [iwlmvm]
[  539.021411]  iwl_pcie_rx_handle+0x3c5/0xa80 [iwlwifi]
[  539.021456]  iwl_pcie_irq_rx_msix_handler+0x55/0xe0 [iwlwifi]
[  539.882063] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x75cc, CPU2 Status: 0xb03
[  539.882110] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: UMAC PC: 0xc0080d9c
[  539.882134] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: LMAC PC: 0x4d0766
[  539.882142] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired.
[  539.883298] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[  539.883302] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: Status: 0x00000000, count: 6
[  539.883307] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 66.55c64978.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-66.ucode
[  539.883312] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000084 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UNKNOWN       
[  539.883318] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x002002F0 | trm_hw_status0
[  539.883323] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[  539.883327] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x004DA1A2 | branchlink2
[  539.883331] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x004D0766 | interruptlink1
[  539.883335] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x004D0766 | interruptlink2
[  539.883338] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x004D8F5A | data1
[  539.883342] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x01000000 | data2
[  539.883346] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000000 | data3
[  539.883349] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[  539.883353] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x000E36EC | tsf low
[  539.883357] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[  539.883361] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[  539.883365] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x000F5740 | time gp2
[  539.883368] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
[  539.883372] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000042 | uCode version major
[  539.883376] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x55C64978 | uCode version minor
[  539.883381] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000420 | hw version
[  539.883384] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x18C89002 | board version
[  539.883388] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x8005FC00 | hcmd
[  539.883392] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00020000 | isr0
[  539.883396] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr1
[  539.883399] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x48F00002 | isr2
[  539.883403] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00C0000C | isr3
[  539.883407] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4
[  539.883411] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
[  539.883414] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x004D8F5A | wait_event
[  539.883418] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[  539.883422] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[  539.883425] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[  539.883429] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[  539.883432] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000009 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[  539.883436] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[  539.883440] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000020 | flow_handler
[  539.883503] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[  539.883506] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: Status: 0x00000000, count: 7
[  539.883511] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x20000066 | NMI_INTERRUPT_HOST
[  539.883516] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[  539.883520] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x8045DFC6 | umac branchlink2
[  539.883524] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x8047FA96 | umac interruptlink1
[  539.883528] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x8047FA96 | umac interruptlink2
[  539.883532] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x01000000 | umac data1
[  539.883536] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x8047FA96 | umac data2
[  539.883540] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac data3
[  539.883543] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000042 | umac major
[  539.883547] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x55C64978 | umac minor
[  539.883551] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x000F5871 | frame pointer
[  539.883554] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0xC088625C | stack pointer
[  539.883558] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000000 | last host cmd
[  539.883562] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000400 | isr status reg
[  539.883596] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: IML/ROM dump:
[  539.883599] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000B03 | IML/ROM error/state
[  539.883622] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x000075CC | IML/ROM data1
[  539.883639] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: Fseq Registers:
[  539.883654] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x60000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[  539.883669] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x80440003 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[  539.883684] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00080009 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[  539.883699] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x0000A652 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[  539.883714] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000002 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[  539.883728] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[  539.883743] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00400410 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[  539.883758] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00400410 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[  539.883773] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00400410 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[  539.883790] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00400410 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[  539.883807] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00009061 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[  539.883824] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000061 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[  539.883841] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[  539.883954] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: WRT: Unassigned region id 1, skipping
[  539.883959] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: WRT: Unassigned region id 8, skipping
[  539.883962] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: WRT: Unassigned region id 9, skipping
[  539.883965] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: WRT: Unassigned region id 10, skipping
[  539.883968] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: WRT: Unassigned region id 11, skipping
[  539.883971] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: WRT: Unassigned region id 12, skipping
[  539.883974] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: WRT: Unassigned region id 15, skipping
[  539.883977] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: WRT: Unassigned region id 16, skipping
[  539.883980] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: WRT: Unassigned region id 17, skipping
[  539.883983] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: WRT: Unassigned region id 18, skipping
[  539.883986] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: WRT: Unassigned region id 19, skipping
[  539.883989] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: WRT: Unassigned region id 20, skipping
[  539.883991] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: WRT: Unassigned region id 21, skipping
[  539.883994] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: WRT: Unassigned region id 22, skipping
[  539.883997] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: WRT: Unassigned region id 23, skipping
[  539.884001] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: WRT: Unassigned region id 24, skipping
[  539.884004] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: WRT: Unassigned region id 26, skipping
[  539.896219] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

2021/08/10's status

```
$ ls -al /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1413868  6月 23 03:55 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-59.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1455104  8月 10 15:54 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-62.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1460012  8月 10 15:54 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-63.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1477864  8月 10 15:54 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-66.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   27480  8月 10 15:54 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm
```

```
$ modinfo iwlwifi 
filename:       /lib/modules/5.11.0-25-generic/updates/dkms/iwlwifi.ko
version:        iwlwifi-stack-public:master:8613:3ae69204
license:        GPL
author:         Intel Corporation <linuxwifi@intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3168-29.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8265-36.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000C-36.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-ma-a0-mr-a0-57.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-ma-a0-gf-a0-57.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-SoSnj-a0-hr-b0-57.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-SoSnj-a0-gf-a0-57.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-SoSnj-a0-gf4-a0-57.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-57.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-57.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-57.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-so-a0-jf-b0-57.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-cc-a0-57.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-b0-jf-b0-57.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-57.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-57.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-57.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-57.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-b0-hr-b0-57.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-57.ucode
```

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep iwl
[    4.701052] Loading modules backported from iwlwifi
[    4.701053] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:8613:3ae69204
[    4.735859] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.757805] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-57.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.758206] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-56.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.758347] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-55.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.758566] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-54.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.758583] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-53.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.758602] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-52.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.758618] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-51.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.758632] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-50.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.758648] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-49.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.758665] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-48.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.758682] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-47.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.758701] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-46.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.758719] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-45.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.758733] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-44.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.758749] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-43.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.758766] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-42.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.758781] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-41.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.758797] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-40.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.758816] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-39.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.758818] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: no suitable firmware found!
[    4.767124] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: minimum version required: iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-39
[    4.767128] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: maximum version supported: iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-57
[    4.767130] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: check git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
```

Under here initial state on make question.

```
~~~@~~~:/lib/modules/5.12.19-051219-generic$ sudo dmesg | grep iwl
[    1.820966] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    1.825029] iwlwifi: No config found for PCI dev 2725/1674, rev=0x420, rfid=0x10d000
[    1.837845] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:30:00.0 failed with error -22
```

```
~~~@~~~:/lib/modules/5.12.19-051219-generic$ modinfo iwlwifi
filename:       /lib/modules/5.12.19-051219-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Intel Corporation <linuxwifi@intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3168-29.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8265-36.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000C-36.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-SoSnj-a0-mr-a0-62.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-ma-a0-mr-a0-62.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-ma-a0-gf4-a0-62.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-ma-a0-gf-a0-62.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-ma-a0-hr-b0-62.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-SoSnj-a0-jf-b0-62.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-SoSnj-a0-hr-b0-62.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-SoSnj-a0-gf-a0-62.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-SoSnj-a0-gf4-a0-62.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-62.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-62.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-62.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-so-a0-jf-b0-62.ucode
~~~
alias:          pci:v00008086d00007E40sv*sd*bc*sc*i*

alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001201bc*sc*i*
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           iwlwifi
vermagic:       5.12.19-051219-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        1F:70:E6:CA:B2:56:2D:B0:6D:8B:3F:1B:51:45:1F:E0:1F:17:F0:31
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
signature:      67:87:40:3B:8A:48:03:CC:67:43:32:A9:04:B2:B8:A8:73:32:B4:70:
        E1:63:FF:84:F0:7A:8B:A5:40:3B:92:EA:98:AD:53:92:0B:18:0A:D2:
        9D:8D:FD:86:E6:E6:57:A9:9F:BC:90:80:17:24:3A:72:5A:6D:B9:AC:
        2B:00:A0:15:D5:D5:5E:B4:68:62:19:B3:98:FB:FF:41:A7:FB:5E:EF:
        67:B5:CC:E8:2F:D6:70:58:A7:DD:9C:9D:22:B8:71:53:12:0E:48:8E:
        D8:74:B9:86:0C:C2:0E:25:32:20:E1:73:C8:37:C4:0A:D6:1E:A7:18:
        C4:14:2D:A5:0C:EE:64:34:50:AE:E3:0D:07:E6:29:DB:02:B4:F4:85:
        42:63:14:30:46:34:62:B6:ED:53:C0:43:5A:1C:3C:0E:E2:7F:34:FE:
        30:9C:42:D0:1C:3E:57:E3:01:6A:EE:A2:49:E3:4B:BF:FD:B6:89:55:
        AA:F8:1B:A0:E1:3C:5E:8D:CE:7D:1C:1E:D1:EC:59:2F:29:CF:65:13:
        B3:16:67:B8:EC:B5:BC:DF:88:F8:6B:6C:2B:2C:AA:6C:26:B8:66:39:
        1E:3E:77:56:62:1F:EF:6C:26:C4:CC:FE:52:D7:63:67:72:B7:B3:6D:
        FF:EB:09:8D:6F:13:79:97:17:EB:42:56:27:D8:69:CC:FA:61:E9:D8:
        FC:B7:C9:EB:35:72:60:49:19:55:9A:D7:01:F0:84:39:96:9B:AD:92:
        7D:3B:73:5C:EC:E6:B2:E0:4F:5D:A8:FA:BE:C8:3E:4C:3E:B7:1D:CE:
        42:7C:1C:F7:41:DD:CD:08:AA:7C:C2:6A:1D:79:20:4A:C3:50:6B:55:
        91:0E:F5:D3:0F:D4:82:01:62:3B:DD:9E:36:E7:1B:DC:54:C2:EE:A5:
        B1:BF:F3:56:F8:77:E7:63:F3:BE:40:C1:A6:70:32:F4:C1:2A:E1:8B:
        1A:A0:63:7D:09:2D:B4:4D:AE:16:E2:DA:88:1D:CE:EB:3C:1A:93:F6:
        D6:8D:CF:72:DD:21:2D:A9:8F:E2:46:10:BD:2B:90:0A:55:A2:BD:E8:
        D5:81:E0:3E:30:82:50:90:08:5D:D0:20:08:7F:0E:2F:66:CC:CB:ED:
        D6:88:6B:22:03:71:40:74:EF:79:9B:A7:96:0A:8E:E4:CE:50:0D:6B:
        AA:0F:C7:11:29:E4:03:49:7B:18:C3:BE:61:7D:8B:7D:E5:B2:20:A3:
        8B:05:FF:AA:02:60:27:52:08:AB:0D:07:B1:57:BF:C8:C4:27:40:C8:
        C9:9B:13:69:AE:0C:0D:6C:B9:6C:ED:7A:39:C0:3E:07:15:10:C4:C3:
        F4:89:5F:58:70:85:4D:FC:FA:3E:6D:93
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size:amsdu size 0: 12K for multi Rx queue devices, 2K for AX210 devices, 4K for other devices 1:4K 2:8K 3:12K (16K buffers) 4: 2K (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality bitmap 1: BSS 2: P2P Client (default: 3) (uint)
parm:           enable_ini:Enable debug INI TLV FW debug infrastructure (default: true (bool)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           disable_11ac:Disable VHT capabilities (default: false) (bool)
parm:           remove_when_gone:Remove dev from PCIe bus if it is deemed inaccessible (default: false) (bool)
parm:           disable_11ax:Disable HE capabilities (default: false) (bool)
```

```
~~~~@~~~~:/lib/modules/5.12.19-051219-generic$ sudo lshw | grep network -A11
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: Killer E3000 2.5GbE Controller
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:2e:00.0
                logical name: enp46s0
                version: 06
                serial: d8:bb:c1:25:33:d7
                capacity: 1Gbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
--
           *-network UNCLAIMED
                description: Network controller
                product: Intel Corporation
                vendor: Intel Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:30:00.0
                version: 1a
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
                configuration: latency=0
                resources: memory:84200000-84203fff
--
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@3:6
       logical name: wlxc006c303b120
       serial: c0:06:c3:03:b1:20
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl88XXau driverversion=5.12.19-051219-generic ip=192.168.10.52 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11AC
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show me `ls -al /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0*`. Thanks~

Comment: thank you comment! I add this info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This procedure is highly experimental and we appreciate that you voluntered to be our tester!

The procedure is outlined here but with a few modifications: [Intel AX201 Wi-Fi 6 is not working on Ubuntu 21.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352653/intel-ax201-wi-fi-6-is-not-working-on-ubuntu-21-04/1353300#1353300)

First, we note that you’ve installed a later mainline kernel in an attempt to get the wireless working:

> 5.12.19-051219-generic

It did not help, as you’ve seen. I suggest that you boot into the latest default Ubuntu kernel version at the GRUB menu. In my 21.04 installation, it is 5.11.0-25-generic.

Next, carefully follow each step in the answer I linked until you make the changes to the file drv.c. Your change will be a bit different.

Edit the drv.c file in the source code directory /usr/src/backport-iwlwifi-8613/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/pcie

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/src/backport-iwlwifi-8613/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/pcie/drv.c
```

Enable "Display line numbers" in Gedit preferences

Add the following line below the other 0x2725 ID lines at #359…

```
{IWL_PCI_DEVICE(0x2725, 0x1674, iwlax210_2ax_cfg_ty_gf_a0)},
```

Save and close the text editor.

Thereafter, the process is the same as I linked. After a reboot, your wireless should be working.

Comment: This may require additional firmware files outlined in robert_s answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1326386/ubuntu-20-04-lts-driver-intel-wi-fi-6e-ax210-160mhz

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I tried and did modprobe, then made some changes in dmesg, but wifi not working.. I add the message on the top question.

Comment: Please try: `sudo cp /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-59.ucode  /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-57.ucode` Reboot and show us: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: @chili555 Good idea. It seems that the original iwlwifi.ko looked for -62, and the backport looks for -57 through -39. I couldn't find any of those versions at the Intel firmware web site at https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git

Comment: thank you guys, I found maximum number is defined on #define IWL_22000_UCODE_API_MAX  in 22000.c https://github.com/intel/backport-iwlwifi/blob/c02f7b1eb7d2d1e3eb174f95cdf1a4913094b3b0/iwlwifi-stack-dev/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/cfg/22000.c
And for some reason this number was 57, so I changed it to 66 then reinstall dkms, I found AX210 in dmesg! However, still cannot connect to wifi...

Comment: sudo cp /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-59.ucode  /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-57.ucode 
I tried this but it wan not effective in the situation.

Comment: this error is similar to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218141/dell-vostro-5490-no-wifi-in-ubuntu-18-04/1224054#1224054 , but not sure how to apply my situation.(Is this a file name problem?)

Comment: Is this a dual boot with Windows? Is Fast Boot enabled or disabled? https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled

Comment: no, but dualboot with ubuntu20. Fais Boot disabled.

Comment: "0000:30:00.0: loaded firmware version 66.55c64978.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-66.ucode op_mode iwlmvm" Do you get the same errors if you rename all the firmware files to xx.bak *except* for -57 which is actually -59 but renamed? I don't think the driver and hardware like -66.

Comment: "iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 59.601f3a66.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-57.ucode" I set 59.ucode as 57.ucode and renname 59,62,63,66.ucode to .bak files, then dmesg showed this.

Comment: iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: loaded firmware version 59.601f3a66.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-59.ucode op_mode iwlmvm

Comment: That's it?? There surely must be more. Please reboot and run: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && sudo dmesg | grep iwl` Paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: oh, thank you inform convenient tool! Here is entire "sudo dmesg | grep wifi" https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ZQyDWTd4GN/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128565/discussion-between-chili555-and-k-ish0212).

Comment: In Ubuntu 22.04, the AX210 works without issues, needing no further changes.

Answer (score 1):

@Chili555 Gave the correct answer in one of the chats in the answers above. I have MSI 76GE Raider. With AX210

```
lspci -nnk

31:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2725] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. Device [1a56:1674]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Had to download and install

```
sudo dpkg -i backport-iwlwifi-dkms_9340-0ubuntu4_all.deb
```

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/impish/amd64/backport-iwlwifi-dkms/9340-0ubuntu4

Plus download firmware from:

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
into /lib/firmware

```
sudo tar -zxvf linux-firmware-20210818.tar.gz -C /lib/firmware
```

Then reboot and all was good. I am running on 5.11.0-34-generic Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Thanks Will, this worked for me on an MSI GP66 Leopard 11UH-251 with a Killer 6E AX1675 running on on 5.11.0-34-generic Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

current solution: change wifi card from AX210 to AX200
It worked for me. This way is easy but official support can't be received. If anyone try this, this youtube will be helpful. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J5Si0_41CZ0

If anyone solve this problem, please let us know..

Comment: Had you tried @chili555 answer?

Comment: I can confirm ax210 / ax1675 loads and works in latest build of Ubuntu 21.10
I am using a MSI GE66 11uh

Comment: great! which kernel do you use and any other installations? @DrewJohnston

Comment: Just the latest from http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/ - nothing else was needed .. it saw the wifi card in the installation wizard

Comment: thank you! I tried it and confirmed AX210 working on kernel 5.13 with ubuntu21.10! but I check only in USB boot mode and using kernel 5.13 fails on my laptop..

Comment: Is it related to nvidia-driver? ( i install it and upgrade to 21.10)

Comment: I installed backport-iwlwifi-dkms on ubuntu21.10 and follow the instruction from chili555 above then AX210 worked! (on 21.10 backport version is 9340)

Comment: Hum... I have the same laptop and it is not even finding by NVME drive on stable release of Ubuntu 21.10.

Comment: It turns out just installing `backport-iwlwifi-dkms` on Ubuntu 21.10 (stable) and using "old" 5.11.0.37 kernel fixed all the issues that I have.

Answer (score 0):

Following update queries helped me to resolve the issue.

```
wget https://anduin.linuxfromscratch.org/sources/linux-firmware/iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-68.ucode
sudo cp iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-68.ucode /usr/lib/firmware/
```

and the pvnm file

```
wget https://anduin.linuxfromscratch.org/sources/linux-firmware/iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0.pnvm
sudo cp iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0.pnvm /usr/lib/firmware/
```

and it works.

**Ref:** https://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org/msg1847049.html