# AX210 WiFi adapter doesn't work on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, kernel 5.11.0-27

Tags: wireless, 20.04, thinkpad, iwlwifi

I just bought brand new Lenovo ThinkPad T15 Gen 2 20W4000GRT and trying to run fresh downloaded Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS on it. Everything looks great besides absence of WiFi (Bluetooth has been detected though).
I have read all the amount of suggestions regarding this issue other people had, but all of them mostly boil down to update kernel to 5.10+ version. My `uname -r` reporting me

```
$ uname -r
5.11.0-27-generic
```

so I figured out there is something else I missing? Updating drivers by Intel from https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html doesn't help as well.

Here is output of `dmesg | grep -i iwl`:

```
$ dmesg | grep -i iwl
[   47.818703] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[   47.818717] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 93.8.63.28
[   47.818987] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: loaded firmware version 59.601f3a66.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-59.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[   48.241025] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz, REV=0x420
[   48.407346] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: loaded PNVM version 0x324cd670
[   48.509642] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Timeout waiting for PNVM load!
[   48.509646] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[   48.509650] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: iwl_trans_send_cmd bad state = 1
[   48.713770] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: firmware didn't ACK the reset - continue anyway
[   48.725941] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

And here is `$ sudo lshw -c network` output:

```
$ sudo lshw -c network
  *-network                 
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       version: 1a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:bc300000-bc303fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (13) I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 20
       serial: 38:f3:ab:b8:ab:6b
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.11.0-27-generic firmware=0.8-3 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:158 memory:bcf00000-bcf1ffff
```

Comment: Can you please boot to a Ubuntu Live 21.04 DVD/USB and see if it works there? Report back.

Comment: Also see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1356118/ax210-wifi-not-working-on-ubuntu21-04

Comment: @heynnema thank you for your advice! You were right, 21.04 work great! Seems like 5.11.0-16 kernel fixed it back. Now I have to figure out how to update kernel on another system w/o online connection.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1360175/intel-wifi-5-ax210-wifi-not-working-after-update for more info about this not working.