# Detailed info of wireless device not shown in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: drivers, wireless, 19.10

My laptop is Dell Vostros 5391 with Win 10 pre-installed. I install Ubuntu by erasing the whole disk. Wifi works after a clean offline installation. But if I do security update for ‘Ubuntu Base’, wifi will not work, and wifi adapter cannot be found. Now my system is Ubuntu 19.10 from its website, with no update of ‘Ubuntu Base’.

I can see some info about my device by `lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9b61 (rev 0c)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 9b41 (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 0c)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 02f9
00:13.0 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Device 02fc
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 02ed
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 02ef
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 02f0
00:14.5 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Device 02f5
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 02e8
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 02e9
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 02e0
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 02b4 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 0284
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device 02c8
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 02a3
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 02a4
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Sandisk Corp Device 5004 (rev 01)
```

The info of wireless device should be like this
`04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9260 (rev 29)`,
but mine is shown like this
`00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 02f0`

By `lspci -s 00:14.3 -v`, I can see driver is `iwlwifi`

```
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 02f0
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 42a4
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at a1218000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Result of `dmesg | grep iwlwifi` can show that the wireless device can be detected, and firmware can be loaded.

```
[    2.189931] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.207176] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 43.2.23.17
[    2.207503] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 48.4fa0041f.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.286360] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 9462, REV=0x354
[    2.405660] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: 5c:80:b6:4f:c4:5a
[    2.420413] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlp0s20f3: renamed from wlan0
```

IResult of `rfkill list` is this:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Kernel is `5.3.0-18-generic`.

In GNOME, 'Software & Update' -> 'Additional Drivers', I can see the device is 
'Intel Corporation: Unknown
This device is not working.',
and three options:
'Using iwlwifi driver backport in DKMS format from backport-iwlwifi-dkms(open source)
Continue using a manually installed driver
Do not use the device'
While the default is selected to the third option, the first and third option is shown in grey.

The problem is similar, but not the same as this one: >[Intel Wireless AC 9462 not working w/ 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182722/intel-wireless-ac-9462-not-working-w-18-04-lts)

Wifi works now. If I do security update for 'Ubuntu Base' in 'Software Updater' after a clean installation, my wifi will not work. I hope that problem can be solved after this one.

==================Edit=====================

After `sudo update-pciids`, it looks like this

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9b61 (rev 0c)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 0c)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Thermal Subsytem
00:13.0 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Integrated Sensor Solution
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 02ed
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 02ef
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9462
00:14.5 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Device 02f5
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Serial IO I2C Host Controller
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Serial IO I2C Host Controller
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Management Engine Interface
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 02b4 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 0284
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device 02c8
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 02a3
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake SPI (flash) Controller
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Sandisk Corp Device 5004 (rev 01)
```

Some info is updated, some not. Wireless device info is updated.

In 'Software & Update' -> 'Additional Drivers', nothing changes. It still says: 'Intel corporation unknown. This device is not working. '

Comment: See if `sudo update-pciids` gets the description updated

Comment: @Eric It is OK really. If you keep fighting on what is "shown", you can achieve that the device will stop working. I don't see any reason to do anything with that. Yes, not all tools show the device correctly, but this is a matter if time.

Comment: @Pilot6 Thanks men. I thought this problem is related to the wireless failure after update.